# Why do I get wrong prediction when using this polynomial forecasting formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, forecasting

I would like to do a forecasting on a growth per period.

I have a formula of polynomial regression
`y = -5E-05x2 + 0.0348x + 0.7148`.

I translated it to:
`=EXP(-5)-0.5*(B4)^2+0.0348*B4+0.7148`
where `B4` is the period running number (I have 365 days, so `B4` is the first period ,`C4`is the next period etc)

I have strange results (my prediction decreases over time instead of getting increased)  so I guess I didn't interpret Excel's formula well.

How can I resolve this problem?

An image of the chart and Excel's formula:

[image]

Comment: It isn't exponential - your first figure is -.00005X2. try `-0.00005*(B4)^2+0.0348*B4+0.7148`

Comment: @brettdj I think it should be `-0.00005`

Comment: @user3964075 5*10^(-5) = .00005

Comment: @brettdj looks like we both edited the comments

Comment: @user3964075 LOL indeed!

Comment: Hello  @brettdj  I tried your formula but it is far away from the prediction that I see on the chart . for example on point time 365 I have an actual value of $ 7.250 and by using your formula I get $0.96447869 while the forecasting value is about 6.8 as i see on the chart.

Comment: If you post your full data set we can tale a look, the formula I posted is consistent with the regression you show above.

Comment: @mql4beginner something is wrong with your calculations, with `365` in `B4` the formula evaluates to `6.7555`

Comment: Hello @ user3964075, I uploaded the data set.thank you both..

Comment: Found my mistake.. It was wrong referance cell.Thank you guys..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-5E-05` isn't `exp(-5)-5`

it is `-5 * 10^(-5)`

for clarification: `-7E-05` means: `-7 * 10^(-5) = -.00007`

Comment: This had been answered above in the comments. Not much point simply repeating it.

Comment: Hi, true, I didn't see the comments when I posted the answer, which, now that I see the comments is identical. Would you like me to remove the answer?

Comment: No need, OP found it useful and accepted it so suggest you leave it as is.